# MVC5 User.Identity.GetUserName() is Null in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

What's going on here? User.Identity.GetUserName() works fine in a view, e.g in the logon partial view. But if I use it in a controller it throws a null reference exception.

I'm looking at the page, and the UserName is displayed in the header, then if I click on a link to a controller where I've tried to use it I get a null reference exception.

I should add, if I do it this way it works fine:

```
        var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        _userName = httpContext != null ? httpContext.User.Identity.Name : "Testing";
```

So mostly I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put the code to invoke `User.Identity.GetUserName();`? If it was on constructor then you'll get that null reference exception -- cause object User is not initialized yet in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The `User` object is exposed to the Controller, so you don't need to access it via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

```
var myUserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

Comment: That's precisely what I did Brendan, and it was throwing a null reference exception.

Comment: Is the controller flagged as AllowAnonymous?  If you have a view from the same controller working fine, then there may be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
public static class GetUserName
{
    public static string Name(IPrincipal user)
    {
        return user==null? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name:user.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you don't have

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

in your Web.config like I just had.